# How to add Custom Font (Roboto) in React-Native with Nativewind CSS application

Tags: react-native, expo, tailwind-css, nativewind

I am new to Nativewind CSS and I need to add Custom font in my React-Native application.

I have tried creating a fonts folder in assets ('/assests/font') and added all the fonts and tried to use in the application. But it didn't work.

Comment: Here you can find an expo example https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/#usage